# calling class using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i am preparing an applicaion in PHP, and using lots of AJAX. So i am doing some ajax and calling classess through ajax includes page but things not working error occuring:

> No such file in directory

Below is a ajax in which i have included a page for calling a class.

```html
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/xyz.php",
    type: "post",
    data: '&xyz=' + zyx + '&task=delete',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
        $('#loaders').hide();
    }
});
```

And below is how i am calling class on included page.

```html
<?php
if($_POST['task'] == "xzs")
{
    include '../core/init.php';
    $DeleteObj = new deleteCls($_POST['xyz']);
    echo $DeleteObj->deletion();
}
```

but result is

> no such directory.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think $_POST['task'] == "delete"?

Comment: please try a manual url, and comment the one which is working

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change this code :`include '../core/init.php';` to some code like this : `include __DIR__.'../core/init.php';` . Also you can `echo __DIR__;` to see your work dir;

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
if($_POST['task'] == "xzs")
```

To

```
if($_POST['task'] == "delete")
```